# Preferred way of grouping utility functions in Scala?

Tags: scala, code-organization

What's the best way of grouping utility functions that don't belong in a class? In Ruby, I would have grouped them in a module. Should I use traits in Scala for the same effect, or objects?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Usually, I put utility functions that are semantically different into different traits and create an object for each trait, e.g.

```
trait Foo {
  def bar = 1
}
object Foo extends Foo
```

That way I'm most flexible.  I can import the utility functions via an `import` statement or via `with` in the class declaration.  Moreover I can easily group different utility traits together into a new object to simplify the import statements for the most commonly used utility functions, e.g.

```
object AllMyUtilites extends Foo with Foo2
```

Comment: I consider `with` to be a bad practice, since it pollutes the types, gives less flexibility (you can skip and rename with `import`s), and you never need your classes to be also utility classes, only when you group your utilities together. So, I'd stay with `object`s or use `with` only for grouping.

Comment: This is great, I was thinking whether to have a trait _or_ an object, but you can have _both_!! =)

Answer (score 7):

Package objects or just plain objects.

See, for instance, `Scala.Predef` and `scala.math`.

Comment: What if you want to take advantage of subtype polymorphysm

Answer (score 2):

Traits if you want them to be mixed in with the classes that are going to use it. Objects if you want to only have to import them.

Comment: If you have utility functions for different OS, wouldn't it be better to have them as traits? That way some behaviour could be inherited?

Comment: @Geo, what you mean? Same interface with different implementations (one for each OS) ? Then it's a lot more than utility functions, it's more of a design concern (a requirement perhaps).